# Is the App or the iPhone causing the issue?

Tags: iphone

So about a month ago I started using the Nike+ GPS app and everything was working fine until a few days ago while using it, my ipod starts skipping and the voice control automatically pops up. At first I thought the app had glitches but then even after i close the app, my ipod was still skipping and that voice control thing popped up. So should I restore? Is there a problem with my phone itself? Or is the app the one that caused this issue?

Thanks in advance for your input.

Comment: Is your home button stuck? Or the button on your headphones?

Comment: Delete the app, run for a day or two and let us know the answer!

Comment: Hmm, you know, I think my home button is the issue now that you ask me. Because sometimes i tap it and it doesn't respond right away.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's the app that's causing the issue. And I believe there are two separate issues with separate causes.

First, the skipping issue could be caused by a corrupt iPhone music DB - this is fixable by re-syncing the iPhone with iTunes.

Second, voice control could kick in automatically if you use some kind of accessory such as headphones. Try not using this accessory for a while and see whether the voice-control issue is sorted.